# how to keep subsections in the below code

Tags: table-of-contents

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item Introduction \hfill 1
\item Literature Survey \hfill 5
\item Objectives \hfill 7 
\item Equipment and Apparatus Required \hfill 15
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: That looks suspiciously like a table of contents, and you don't want to generate that manually. Just add `\tableofcontents` where the ToC should be printed. The look can be customized of course.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem and what you are trying to do, which is unclear here. A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 3):

There is no sense of making the table of contents manually. Instead, please use `\tableofcontents` and LaTeX will prepare it for you.

*Example*

```
\documentclass{report}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Virtual}
\section{First  Section}
\clearpage
\subsection{First  Subsection}
\clearpage
\subsection{Second  Subsection}
\clearpage
\section{Second  Section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: in the above of this i have to write the     Nomenclature, list of figures, and tables. If I use as u said these are coming at the end of the page

Comment: @yvenkat `\usepackage{tocbibind}` will automatically add most of such things to the ToC.